# Supposed acronym expansions for common words

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms

I have seen expansions of many English words such as *POLICE*, *MUSIC*, *GOD*, *LASER*, where each letter supposedly stands for another word, as in an acronym. Are these expansions in any way real, that is, written in a standard dictionary, or are they just made up?

Comment: I don't see how "God" or "music" became acronyms or abbreviations... but "laser" certainly is an acronym.

Comment: [In any event...](http://www.acronymfinder.com/)

Comment: It should be noted that an acronym is just one possible type of abbreviation, they're not necessarily the same thing: http://encarta.msn.com/dictionary_/abbreviation.html

Comment: This question needs some rewrite, it's not really clear what the question means...

Comment: Only one of the examples you list (laser) is an acronym. In light of that, I have very little idea what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: I also do not understand what this question is asking.

Comment: @Martha, @Kosmonaut - I took the first half of the question (before the ?) to mean that the Evangelist wanted to know if certain acronyms were also included in the dictionary as words in their own right, which is what I answered.  The second half I took at first to mean that examples of other words like this would be good too, but now am not so certain.

Comment: @J.M. here is abbreviation of GOD G=Genarator 0=Operator D=Destructor

Answer (score 4):

Police is not an acronym or abbreviation, normally. You could make a [backronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym) for it if you wanted.

Maybe

> People Ostensibly Licensed In Crime Eradication

In general, any word older than the 1950s is pretty much guaranteed not to be derived from an acronym. There are exceptions, but if someone tells you a word is really an acronym, just disbelieve until you've checked a reputable reference.

Comment: *People Of Low Intelligence Collecting Evidence*

Answer (score 3):

The word laser was originally an acronym, which stood for:

```
Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation - LASER
```

According to the [Oxford on-line dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0458250#m_en_gb0458250) entry for laser, this originated in the 1960s.

However, through common usage, the word laser has been adopted in its own right and is defined as:

> a device that generates an intense
>   beam of coherent monochromatic light
>   (or other electromagnetic radiation)
>   by stimulated emission of photons from
>   excited atoms or molecules. Lasers are
>   used in drilling and cutting ,
>   alignment and guidance, and in
>   surgery; the optical properties are
>   exploited in holography, reading
>   barcodes, and in recording and playing
>   compact discs.

There are other examples of acronyms that have been adopted into the English language as words in their own right:

[RADAR - RAdio Detection And Ranging](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0682900#m_en_gb0682900) - defined as:

> a system for detecting the presence,
>   direction, distance, and speed of
>   aircraft, ships, and other objects, by
>   sending out pulses of radio waves
>   which are reflected off the object
>   back to the source.

[SCUBA - Self-Contained Underwater Breathing Apparatus](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0744770#m_en_gb0744770) - defined as:

> an aqualung.

Comment: It should be noted that science-fiction writers have back-formed laser into a verb, `to lase`: "He was lased by the laser."

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New - Dictionary.reference.com agrees with you, but the Oxford on-line dictionary provides a slightly different definition and the Cambridge on-line dictionary doesn't contain the verb at all.  Do you have a reference I can read?

Comment: I don't have a reference for it. But I have seen it in actual books. I'd call it a recent coining and non-standard. Sci-fi writers are always doing that sort of thing.

Comment: If you googlesearch http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22he+was+lased%22 you'll see that people are using it that way in non-sci-fi writing as well.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: It's not just science fiction writers.  I've also heard the term used scientifically, to describe the process that occurs in a laser when the ratio of photons stimulated to photons lost exceeds unity.  The term may be a back formation, but it would be difficult to discuss concisely the intricacies of lasers without being able to use such a verb.

Answer (score 0):

Some other examples:

- Maser: "Microwave Amplification..."
- Modem: "modulator/demodulator"
- Codec: "coder/decoder"
- Jeep: "*g*eneral *p*urpose"